# Extract matched keyword and its matching line or paragraph as regex submatches

Tags: arrays, excel, regex, vba, powerquery

The following code snippet loops through single-column tables containing keywords, in a keywords sheet and tries matching these concatenated keywords of each column, to a text string (Str) that has been concatenated from an array containing verbatims.

I need a regex pattern that can extract not only the keyword as a submatch, but the entire line/paragraph in which the keyword match was found.

```
    '========================= Grab keyword tables for matching ======================================

    Set dRegex = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dDupl = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    ' Keywords Sheet
    With wkKeywords
        ' find last col on header row 1
        x = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        ' scan across header
        For c = 1 To x
            colname = Trim(.Cells(1, c))
            If Len(colname) > 0 Then
                ' last row
                n = .Cells(.Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp).Row
                
                ReDim ar(0 To n - 2)
                'modify for regex
                For i = 2 To n
                    s = Trim(.Cells(i, c))
                    
                     If Len(s) = 0 Then
                        MsgBox "Nothing in keyword row " & i & " column " & c, vbCritical
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                    ar(i - 2) = Replace(s, "'", "'?") ' optional
                    ar(i - 2) = Replace(ar(i - 2), """", """?")
                Next i
                
                Set dRegex(colname) = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
                With dRegex(colname)
                    .Global = True
                    .MultiLine = False
                    .ignorecase = True
'                    .Pattern = "(\b" & Join(ar, "\b)|(\b") & "\b)"
'                    .Pattern = "((.*?\b" & Join(ar, "\b|\b") & ".*?)(?=\b|$))"
'                    .Pattern = "(\b(" & Join(ar, "|") & ")\b)(.*?(\r\n|\r|\n|$))"
'                    .Pattern = "((.*?)(\b" & Join(ar, "\b|\b") & "\b)(.*?))" '(\r\n|\r|\n|$))"
                    .Pattern = "((?:.*(?:\r\n|\r|\n|$))?(\b" & Join(ar, "\b|\b") & "\b)(?:.*(?:\r\n|\r|\n|$))?)"

                    'Debug.Print colname, n, .Pattern
                End With
            End If
        Next c
    End With
        
    '========================= Transpose data Array ======================================
    tempArr = ArrOut
    Erase ArrOut
    ArrOut = TransposeArray(tempArr)
    
    '========================= Join textual data as a concatenated string for matching ======================================
    
    For i = LBound(ArrOut, 1) To UBound(ArrOut, 1)
        str = str & ArrOut(i, 1) & ":" & ArrOut(i, 2) & vbCr
    Next i
        
Stop

    '========================= Find Matches in textual data ======================================
    For Each colname In dRegex.keys
        Set matches = dRegex(colname).Execute(str)
 '       DoEvents
        Stop
        For i = 0 To (matches.Count - 1)
            For j = 0 To matches(i).submatches.Count - 1
                If Not matches(i).submatches(j) = Empty Then
                    Debug.Print colname, Trim(matches(i).submatches(j))
                End If
            Next j
            Stop
        Next i
        Stop
    Next colname

Stop
```

I have tried a couple of regex patterns and some of them return just the keyword, or the keyword and a part of the paragraph after the keyword or entire paragraphs before and after the keyword.

I just need the entire line or paragraph returned in which the keyword was matched. So a keyword say "eager" could be found in multiple different lines/paragraphs. I want to list the keyword and its matching paragraphs.

The lines/paragraphs in the string could like :

> tody:Never really considered what it could do. But now the question is
> across as far as lack of sleep could affect how your body generates. I
> am eager to know much more. anabelle:Understand it's something to do
> with the body clock. That's all I know really, you can feel
> differently in different times of day, stuff like that. tody:I'd like
> to know if this lotion is long-lasting, and how much it would be and
> how many times you would have to apply it? I know it is said that it
> would take up the six or eight weeks, but how many times would you
> need to apply it? simran:I think this lotion could be different,
> because it works with your rhythm, and when you go to sleep, so it
> could have a more lasting effect, and since you put it on your face at
> the end of the night instead of the morning when you wake up.

Some keywords in one of the keywords columns to be matched in the paragraphs, could be:

```txt
affect
eager
feel differently
long-lasting
different
lasting effect
```

Please note, i don't want to loop the textual data array `ArrOut` by splitting it into individual lines, but want to do it in one go without much looping.

I am not a pro in regex expressions. Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: You can get the match position, so track forward/back to get the start/end of the containing paragraph.

Comment: This is very confusing. There is a whole lot of code that does not do anything with `ArrOut`. It then appears to concatenate the unknown contents of `ArrOut` with some intervening colons and CRs into `str`. If then does some RegExstuff with `str`. Why? Why not search the Excel cells as they are visited and catch those that are interesting?

Comment: Split into paragraph, then  keep those that that have that word.

Comment: @TimWilliams are you referring to the matches item firstindex? I guess it means the starting position of keyword in the paragraph.  Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @AdrianHHH Arrout is the data array and earlier I was looping each array index and testing it against keyword concatenated column i.e. dregex(colname) dictionary key. Since array is large and it takes a lot of time, I plan to concatenate Arrout into a single string of paragraphs separated by vbCr and then find matches for the dregex (colname) keywords in this single string Str. So need a regex pattern that can match the keyword and return the keyword as well as it's paragraph too as submatches.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't want to split the Str. Another thought - If it's possible to atleast find the paragraph row for each keyword match, then using the paragraph row later, the paragraph can also be returned.

Comment: Yes - `FirstIndex` would allow you to use Instr/InStrRev to find the next/previous newlines so you could extract the containing paragraph.

Comment: @TimWilliams I don't know how. What I need is the same line / paragraph in which keyword was found. One of the regex pattern does return keyword as well as paragraph as submatches. But it does not return full paragraph. So I know it is possible to return both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following from my comment about extracting the matched paragraph if you know the match position within the text:

```vb
Sub GetMatchedParagraph()

    Dim txt As String, pos As Long, posB As Long, posE As Long
    
    txt = "This is the first paragraph." & vbLf & _
            "This is the second paragraph." & vbLf & _
            "This is the third paragraph." & vbLf & _
            "This is the fourth paragraph." & vbLf & _
            "This is the fifth paragraph."
    
    pos = InStr(1, txt, "second", vbTextCompare) 'find "second"
    If pos = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    
    'previous newline, or start of text if none
    posB = InStrRev(txt, vbLf, pos)
    If posB = 0 Then posB = 1
    
    'next newline, or end of text if none
    posE = InStr(pos, txt, vbLf)
    If posE = 0 Then posB = Len(txt)
    
    Debug.Print Mid(txt, posB, (posE - posB)) 'the matched paragraph

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. And appreciate everyone's solutions. but they do not serve my purpose. As mentioned, I only need a regex pattern that can return submatches containing keyword and it's matching para.

Comment: Since i wasn't able to find a suitable regex pattern satisfying my need, choosing the next best option i.e. @Tim Williams solution. Thanks Tim :)

Answer (score 3):

This finds the full row text in Table1 that contains each keyword in Table2,  using powerquery

```
//Table2 powerquery code
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source,"Matches",(x)=>Table.SelectRows(Table1, each Text.Contains([Column1],x[Column1],Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))),
#"Expanded Matches" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "Matches", {"Column1"}, {"Text"})
in #"Expanded Matches"
```

[image]

Bring the text into powerquery using data  ... from table/range... then file ... close and load ... connection only.  It should automatically assign name Table1 (or adjust it yourself). Bring the keywords into powerquery using data  ... from table/range... then  paste code into home ... advanced editor... and load back to excel  using file .. close and load ... to table

Comment: the text is in an array and not in any table. Also, i don't to use power query as its difficult to program....though i have some knowledge of m-language.